# Use setuptools to create an executable distribution of a package with --multi-version?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, versioning, software-distribution

I'm trying to create simple Windows executable installers for a Python package that will only be delivered internally to other developers on my team. I'd like to let them install multiple versions of the package at the same time and specify which to run by using different commands: `<package>-0.1`,`<package>-0.2`, etc.

It looks like `setuptools` offers a fairly standard way to install multiple versions of a package: just create an egg for each version of the package, then install each egg using the `--multi-version` option with `easy_install`.

However, rather than providing the eggs and asking developers to use `easy_install` via the command-line, I'd like to just offer something they can run that will automatically perform the installation. `python setup.py bdist_wininst` does *almost* exactly what I want, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to create a `bdist_wininst` that uses the `--multi-version` option (or does anything similar).

Is there a way to accomplish this? I realize I could just manually write an executable program to call `easy_install --multi-version`, but that seems like a ridiculous workaround for something that I'd hope is achievable just using the built-in capabilities of `setuptools`.

---

Tangentially, is there an easy way to have the installer automatically create `<package>-<version>.bat` files for each installed version of the package?

Comment: Woooo, tumbleweed badge. Guess I'll just make do without this feature, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setup.py` script for the [SCons](http://www.scons.org/) project implements this feature using vanilla `distutils`, and the method is also usable with `setuptools`. At the time of writing, the current version of `setup.py` is [here](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/src/03a9d6241942c4f41619b5fc281a8de56ae77216/src/setup.py?at=default). The trick is the use of the `cmdclass` argument to replace `install_lib` with a modified class that inherits from the default `install_lib` class used by `distutils`.

A pared-down version of the same trick, using `setuptools` (note that this is done by simply replacing all instances of `distutils` with `setuptools`):

```
import setuptools.command.install_lib
_install_lib = setuptools.command.install_lib.install_lib
class install_lib(_install_lib):
    def finalize_options(self):
        _install_lib.finalize_options(self)
        self.install_dir = join(self.install_dir,'PKG_NAME-'+PKGVERSION)
```